# Correct/better implementation for the model of a 'Like' in Django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, relational-database, manytomanyfield

I am currently working on a project that requires the implementation of a typical 'like' button on posts (submitted by users).

Which one of the following two implementation would be a better choice considering every aspect - performance, integrity, etc ?

```
class Post(models.Model):
    .
    .
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank = True)
    .
    .
```

or,

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    #considering we have a Post model without the above ManyToMany relation
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    .
    .
```

Comment: These are exactly the same. A many-to-many relationship always involves a through table, explicit or not.

Comment: That's  what I got to know upon researching about it for a bit. However, a colleague of mine says that we should not use a foreign key as it increases the CPU cost. So, I am really confused here. The involvement of a 'through' table will also result in the same cost as 2 FK's, and therefore the implementation won't matter in this case. Right ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what your colleague is saying. The cost of FKs is in extra database queries (or more expensive ones with JOIN). But yes, an implicit through table is exactly the same in terms of db complexity as an explicit one with two FKs.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot!